# Office.js Existence of custom property

Tags: office-js

I am trying to see the existence of custom property using office js. I am having trouble in getting to know the existence.

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {              
            let customDocProperties = context.workbook.properties.custom;
            let customProperty = customDocProperties.getItem("prop");
            customProperty.load("key, value");
            await context.sync();
            console.log(customProperty);
}
```

In the above case, if the property "prop" is available, code works fine without any issues. If there is no "prop" or any customproperties available, the code doesn't proceed further.

How to break the code if there is no such property or no custom properties are available?

Also, I tried the following code. In this case, the code hangs and excel memory spikes up (in GBs) when there is any custom property is available.

```
customDocProperties.load('items');
await context.sync();
console.log(customDocProperties.items.length);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using getItemOrNullObject() instead of getItem(). The following is an example:

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {              
    let customDocProperties = context.workbook.properties.custom;
    let customProperty = customDocProperties.getItemOrNullObject("prop");
    customProperty.load("key, value");
    await context.sync();

    if (customProperty.isNullObject) {
        //Handle case where the custom property does not exist.
    }
    else
        console.log(customProperty);
    })

}
```

For more information, see [CustomPropertyCollection](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/custompropertycollection).

Comment: The advantage of this approach, too, is that you can check the existence of multiple properties at the same time (on the same `context.sync()`), just by creating multiple variables for the different properties.  And/or batch it with other code.  Whereas otherwise, if you rely on a throwing behavior, you would have to do a `context.sync()` call for each property, which is much less performant and more tedious.

Comment: FWIW, there is a chapter about this in my book, [Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins).  The chapter is called "9: Checking if an object exists".  The book is available in e-book form at https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins, with [all profits to charity](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/charity).